# Are Hindi: muskān and Russian: usméška cognates? (Noun smile)

Tags: etymology

This is what I've found so far:

Noun
Hindi: मुस्कान f (muskān) 
Russian: усме́шка (ru) f (usméška)

Verb 
Indo-Iranian: *smáyati
Proto-Slavic: smьjati (*smijàti)

PIE: *(s)meyh₂-

English: Smile

Comment: Fun chance coincidence: Breton *mousc'hoarzh* "smile".

Answer (score 7):

The answer is no. Hindi muskān cannot derive from the Sanskrit root SMI; the vowels do not match. Turner derives it from a hypothetical ancestor *muss.

https://dsalsrv04.uchicago.edu/cgi-bin/app/soas_query.py?qs=muss&searchhws=yes

Comment: Thanks! That hypothetical ancestor *muss, would it belong to some Proto language?

Comment: Possibly a substrate word.

Answer (score 3):

You seem to have answered your own question! To our current understanding, yes, they are cognates, also cognate with English "smile", "smirk", and (less directly, via Latin via French) "admire" and "miracle".

This PIE root is quite well-attested, and has direct descendants in many different Indo-European languages. I don't know enough about Hindi to talk about the derivation there, but in Russian, *-шка* is a productive noun-deriving suffix.

Comment: Yeah, it’d make more sense to compare Russian смех ‘laughter’ or смеяться ‘to laugh’ rather than their derivative усмешка ‘smirk’.

Comment: Why is this incorrect answer being upvoted? See @fdb's answer